# Rails Koala get_connections(post_id) returns 100, no such API call

Tags: ruby-on-rails, facebook, facebook-graph-api, koala

So, I've been stuck the last few hours on something that to me, seems quite weird.

What I'm trying to do is get the likes of a post through the Facebook graph API using Koala. Sounds simple enough.

using

```
@likes = @graph.get_connections("#{post_id}", "likes")
```

This should return an array of id's from the likes of the post, and using graph explorer, I can do this.

What I do is this: I get the id for the post from the Graph API, and let's say it's the final post of myself. So I get the id from the first post in the array of `get_connections("me", "posts")`. And I can also do this via the graph explorer. But when I get the likes from that id, graph explorer gives me an array of id's (no problem there) and Koala returns: 100, no such request.

Does anyone know how I should be able to fix this?

EDIT:

I think the problem lies within getting something using the post_id that's build up like: `UserID_PostID`, since using this on `post = get_object("#{post_id}")` doesn't work either

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was that my access codes weren't refreshed somehow, when I got them refreshed, it was solved. So to anyone experiencing the same problem, I would suggest checking your access tokens